# How to avoid stretching and squishing of PBR texture

Tags: materials, uv

I have a wall with a PBR texture i downloaded, but the wall is not a perfect cube. its smaller on its width than its length, and therefore my texture is kinda squished on the small side.

Additionally i want to cell fracture the wall, but that brings the same problem, just the same textures just that everything is different sizes and squished.

How do i fix this?

Pictures:
[image: FirstProblem]
[image: CellFracture Problem]

File: https://send-anywhere.com/web/downloads/JK8XXTBG

Comment: How does your UV unwrap look like?

Comment: @moonboots Looks like a Cross on the static wall if i understood you correctly, im a beginner if you didnt get it already

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? (upload and copy paste the URL) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/c887e7ddfb114c848dd6a22781164d26

Comment: @moonboots i might have forgot to save, but i think its all there

Comment: You haven't packed the images, so please pack, save and share again (only the useful images and objects)

Comment: @moonboots The website you sent me isnt working anymore for some weird reason ,do you have an alternative?

Comment: use wetransfer for example, send the file to yourself and share the link it will give

Comment: @moonboots http://sendanywhe.re/JK8XXTBG Maby this will work

Comment: @moonboots Thank you will look into it, i tried searching but didnt find this

Comment: 2 things - First select your object in object mode, press Ctrl+A and select "scale" (likely not needed, but removes this from the equation). Then in edit mode, select the whole mesh, press U (unwrap), and select "cube projection". It may not be _perfect_ but it will be a whole lot better.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett, I think you should propose this as answer

Comment: @moonboots _ I proposed as an answer - you can add to it about the loose parts if you like. I haven't seen his file, so I haven't seen that aspect, and I'm not really looking to download 170mb just for a look at a "cube" ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can do to improve the texture "stretching" - First, select your object in object mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select "scale" (likely not needed, but removes this from the equation).

Secondly, in edit mode, select the whole mesh, press U (unwrap), and select "cube projection". This will "create" your UV map. based on a cubic bounding box. It may not be perfect but it will be a whole lot better. The better way would be to mark seams and unwrap manually, but that could be overkill for a simple shape.

Comment: @moonboots If you say this so that the unwrap projects all these UVs within one space, this is not needed since the introduction of multi-object editing back in v2.80. You can just select all those objects and enter edit mode to unwrap them, no object destruction needed.

Comment: @L0Lock, you're right, I don't know why I failed when I tried  ;)